# Mongoose Model Undefined in Pre Middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, typeerror

I am trying to construct an application that acts as a URL shortener like bitly. I have hit a snag, however, and would very much appreciate your help. I was in the process of testing my Link model with mocha and was running into errors in one of my pre middleware functions. In this function I attempt to get a count of all the entries that have a shortened url that matches the one that I just generated, so that I don't double up on my shortened links. In order to do this I am trying to call the Mongoose's count function on my model, but I am getting the TypeError: "cannot read property 'count' of undefined". I have tried to search for why this is happening but have been unable to come up with anything.

If you could help me figure out why this is happening or what a better method would be for generating the shortened links, I would very much appreciate it. Thanks!

You can find my code for my Link model below:

```
'use strict';

let mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    config = require('../../config/config'),
    schema = mongoose.Schema;

let LinkSchema = new schema({
    originalLink: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        validate: [
            function(link) {
                let urlReg = new RegExp("(http|ftp|https)://[\w-]+" +
                    "(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;/~+#-])?");
                return urlReg.test(link);
            }, 'The URL entered is not valid'
        ],
        required: 'URL to shorten is required'
    },
    shortenedLink: String
});

LinkSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    let shortLink;
    let count;
    while (true) {
        console.log(`slink: ${shortLink}, count: ${count}`);
        shortLink = this.generateShortenedLink(this.originalLink);
        mongoose.model['Link'].count({shortenedLink : shortLink}, (err, n) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                next();
            }
            count = n;
        });
        if (count === 0) {
            break;
        }
    }

    this.shortenedLink = shortLink;

    next();
});

LinkSchema.methods.generateShortenedLink = function(link) {
    let text = "";
    let possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++ )
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

    return config.appUrl + text;
};

mongoose.model('Link', LinkSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

`mongoose.model` is a function, and you're using it as if it were an object.

Try this instead:

```
mongoose.model('Link').count(...);
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I missed something so simple, thank you! The issue now seems to be that the code won't even execute the count function. It doesn't break, it just doesn't ever seem to go inside the count callback. When I print out what mongoose.model('Link').count is it tells me [Function: count], so it seems like it should be working. Any ideas?

Comment: Your middleware is calling `next()` (on the last line) before the call to `.count()` has finished. There are also other async issues with it (like a `while (true)` loop which doesn't mix with async functions).

Comment: I don't think it's the next() call that is causing the issue because I put a log statement at the very beginning of the count callback and the code didn't get there. However, what you said about me not doing things in accordance with the async style makes a lot of sense, so clearly I need to rethink about how to go about this. I originally wanted to just mark the shortenedLink field unique, but I couldn't figure out how to go about regenerating a random set of characters if the current set I generated is not unique. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Nevermind, I misunderstood what you were saying about me calling next() at the wrong time, and you are totally right. Thank you so much for all the help, I clearly need to learn how to think more asynchronously.